# How to force persisting data during execution of camel processors rather than the end of the route?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, apache-camel

When i toogle a breakpoint beside the `repository.saveAndFlush` and during de debug mode i see that it returne a new client objet with new Id but when i check in the data base i do not find that client. However, if i do a resume (F8 with eclipse) then i re-check the DB i find the client.

So How to force persisting data during execution of camel processors  rather than the end of the route?

```
   @Component
    public class myRoute extends RouteBuilder {

    @Autowired Processor validationDatasProcessor;
    @Autowired Processor clientProcessor;
    @Autowired Processor endCientProcessor;

    @Override
    public void configure() throws Exception {
        from("queueIn")
        .id("route_processing").messageHistory().transacted()
        .log(LoggingLevel.DEBUG, log, "reception").pipeline()
        .process(validationDatasProcessor)
        .id(validationDatasProcessor.getClass().getSimpleName().toLowerCase())
        .process(clientProcessor)
        .id(clientProcessor.getClass().getSimpleName().toLowerCase())
        .process(endCientProcessor).id(endCientProcessor.getClass().getSimpleName().toLowerCase())
        .to("outputQueue")
        .end();
     }
    }
```

**Processors:**

```
@Component
public class ValidationDatasProcessor implements Processor {

    @Autowired ObjectMapper objectMapper;

    @Autowired ClientRepository clientRepository;

    @Override
    public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
        String clientString = exchange.getIn().getBody(String.class);
        Client client = objectMapper.readValue(clientString, Client.class);
        clientRepository.saveAndFlush(client)
        exchange.setOut(generateOutMessage(client, exchange.getContext()));
    }

    Message generateOutMessage(Client client, CamelContext camelContext) throws JsonProcessingException {
        DefaultMessage outMessage = new DefaultMessage(camelContext);
        outMessage.setBody(objectMapper.writeValueAsString(client), String.class);
        return outMessage;
    }
}

@Component
public class ClientProcessor implements Processor {

    @Autowired ObjectMapper objectMapper;

    @Autowired ClientRepository clientRepository;

    ....

    @Override
    public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
        String clientString = exchange.getIn().getBody(String.class);
        Client client = objectMapper.readValue(clientString, Client.class);
        client.setAccessDate(LocalDateTime.now);
        clientRepository.saveAndFlush(client)
        exchange.setOut(generateOutMessage(client, exchange.getContext()));
    }

    Message generateOutMessage(Client client, CamelContext camelContext) throws JsonProcessingException {
        DefaultMessage outMessage = new DefaultMessage(camelContext);
        outMessage.setBody(objectMapper.writeValueAsString(client), String.class);
        return outMessage;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your entire route is a transacted; which means the whole route is under a transaction scope. A `commit` will be done only after the whole route is executed.

if you want to execute a processor outside the transaction boundary, split the route and use a `seda` endpoint. `seda` are asynchronous and start new threads. They won't participate in the active transaction boundary.

Commiting parts in the middle of a transaction scope doesn't sound like a great idea. Perhaps your rounte needs to be split into multiple fragments.

This [documentation](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_jboss_fuse/6.3/html/transaction_guide/txndemarcation) might help you understand them better.